# Test.setCreatedDate fails on note record created in test context

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I'm trying to get a number of records inserted into the database sometime in the past, to allow for a cleanup batch to have proper test coverage. I can use `Test.setCreatedDate` on the account I'm attaching a number of notes too, but I can't use it on the notes themselves.

```
@isTest 
public static void Test_SetCreatedDate() {
    Note n = new Note();
        
    n.Title = 'Naming Criteria';
    n.Body = 'Testing Note.';
    
    Account a = Generate.CreateAccount();
    
    insert a;
    
    n.ParentId = a.Id;
    
    insert n; 
        
    Test.setCreatedDate(a.Id, DateTime.now().addMonths(-6));
    Test.setCreatedDate(n.Id, DateTime.now().addMonths(-6));
    
    Test.startTest();
    
    a = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM Account WHERE Id = :a.Id];
    n = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM Note WHERE Id = :n.Id];
    
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.now().addMonths(-6), a.CreatedDate);
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.now().addMonths(-6), n.CreatedDate);
    
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

This code is failing with:

```
System.NoDataFoundException: The sObject with the ID 002m0000000m2rjAAA isn’t part of 
this transaction. Provide the ID of an sObject that this test method created.
```

As far as I can tell, this is a test method, with everything (including the `Generate` class), located in a test context.

Heres the `Generate.CreateAccount` function, requested in the comments. All it does is act as a scaffold to provide data that fulfills the requirements for record creation, without inserting a record.

```
private final static User user = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1];

@testVisible
private static Account CreateAccount() {
    Account account = new Account();
    
    account.Name = 'Test';
    account.OwnerId = user.Id;
    account.Description = 'Used for testing.';
    account.NumberOfEmployees = 1;

    // other fields 
    
    return account;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `Generate.CreateAccount();` method

Comment: Just tried this in my developer instance and I get the same exception. Seems very odd.

Comment: Can you move `Test.startTest();` to the first line in your method and try again

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried- but is disallowed and provides only a System.NoAccessException: Use Test.setCreatedDate() only before Test.startTest().

Comment: Since this is a really new feature, it seems like a bug to me. Especially since it does work on the Account record, but it doesn't work for the Note record

Comment: to work around this, use json.deserialize into the Note object; you can inject createdDate that way; there's an alternate strategy as well - code your production code to reference a static property `today` that testmethods can set to any value; then you insert sobjects with createdDate=today's date but the code can pretend to run in the past, present, or future

Comment: @cropredy, I know workarounds exist that I could use for testing, but I'd like to determine why this code fails to run. However, if you post that as an answer, add some code to it, you'll have least have my vote up.

Comment: @battery.cord This will likely need a support case to raise the problem with Notes in setCreatedDate. Can you raise a case, or do you want me to raise one and feed the results back here?

Comment: @DanielBallinger, I attempted to file a case with support, but since the company I work for cannot afford premier support, and developer accounts have no support access, my only option to try and contact salesforce was to post this question onto the Salesforce Success Community forums. If you would be willing to file a case, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue in my org, despite trying many variations and even a direct copy-paste from your post. It's not a universal issue.

Comment: Is `user` from your `Generate` class the running user?

Comment: I've also tried this on a developer org on spring '16 with a modified example which is not dependent on the `Generate` class, and received the same exception. I can add that to the post if you would like to try using it as well.

Comment: The `user` in `Generate` is set via the following line: `private final static User user = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1];`. Ill add it to the original post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've raised support case 13752643 for the problem with Test.setCreatedDate not working with a Note that was created in the test method transaction. I'll relay the important updates from the case here.

See Known Issue [Test.setCreatedDate() does not work for Note object](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jko6)

Update: 17th October - The known issue is now marked as "Fixed - Winter '17"

---

Repo code against v36.0 on na5.

```
@IsTest
public class Test_SettingCreatedDateOnNote {

    @isTest
    public static void CleanUp_Test() {
        Account testAccount = new Account();

        testAccount.Name = 'Test Account';

        insert testAccount;

        System.assertNotEquals(null, testAccount.Id);

        Note testNote = new Note();

        testNote.Title = 'Test Account Note';
        testNote.Body = 'Test Account Note Body.';
        testNote.ParentId = testAccount.Id;

        insert testNote;

        System.assertNotEquals(null, testNote.Id);

        Test.setCreatedDate(testAccount.Id, DateTime.now().addMonths(-6));
        Test.setCreatedDate(testNote.Id, DateTime.now().addMonths(-6));

        Test.startTest();

        System.assert([SELECT COUNT() FROM Note] > 0);

        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

The line `Test.setCreatedDate(testNote.Id, DateTime.now().addMonths(-6));` throws the following exception:

> System.NoDataFoundException: The sObject with the ID 0027000000VBxllAAD isn’t part of this transaction. Provide the ID of an sObject that this test method created.

Comment: FYI I couldn't reproduce on `cs24`. This test passes for me.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Interesting. From the success page I put na5 and cs24 both on   Spring '16 Patch 18.3 currently. I'll find a sandbox to try it on as well. How are you running the test case? I've used the developer console Run Test both sync and async. Both fail.

Comment: Through Sublime/MavensMate. I checked through the UI and Dev Console, works there too.

Comment: Fails for me on NA2

Comment: I predict your next update reads: `We are logging an investigation on the issue for the R&D to determine if this is a bug. The team is looking into the issue. I will keep you updated on the status with my next update between 4 and 5 PM Pacific time tomorrow.`

Comment: @cropredy :) On one hand the updates from support don't add much to the answer. I'll probably remove them once it's resolved. On the other hand, it's a real world example of the support process. To be fair, I didn't indicate that this was a particularly pressing problem in the support case.

Answer (score 10):

For argument's sake, let's assume SFDC will fix the issue with

```
Test.setCreatedDate(n.id,someDateTime)
```

but, until then, two workarounds

**JSON deserialize**

```
Note n = (Note) Json.deserialize('{"createdDate" : "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",' +
                                   '"title" : "foo",' +
                                   '"body" : "fooBody",' +
                                   '"parentId" : "' + a.id + '"' +
                                  '}',
                                  Note.class);
insert n;
```

**Static property in some Util class**

```
public static Date todayDate {
   get {return todayDate == null ? Date.today() : todayDate;}
   set;
}

public static DateTime nowTime {
   get {return nowTime == null ? DateTime.now() : nowTime;}
   set;
}
```

Change all your code references from `...Date.today()...` to `...Util.todayDate...`

for example,

```
if (myNote.createdDate < Util.nowTime) ...
```

or

```
[select id , ... from Opportunity where closeDate < : Util.todayDate]
```

now, your testmethods can set today's date (or now time) to any value in the past, present, or future before or after the objects are created or referenced

Comment: I tried this deserialize method, it doesnt work for account object, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @susanoochidori.  Post a new question showing your code

Comment: here is the link for new question.
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120281/unable-to-set-created-date-even-after-enabling-set-audit-fields

Comment: Thank you!! very much cropredy, actually I stuck here to deploy my code to production. Now I am able to deploy my code to prod with the util class provided by you.

Comment: @Laxman - I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: @cropredy it's not a question, it's a compliment for providing the above piece of code(using util class).