# Unable to Set CreatedDate only on Knowledge__kav

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge, system-permissions, createddate

This question relates very much to [Unable to Set Created date even after enabling Set Audit Fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120281/unable-to-set-created-date-even-after-enabling-set-audit-fields/290615#comment503382_290615)

However, my problem is specifically related to the **Knowledge__kav** SObject.

I'm trying to import existing knowledge articles into salesforce from a legacy system and for compliance reasons, I need to keep the same CreatedDate.

I've given the running user a permission set, which has the permission **"Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation"** enabled.
When trying to set CreatedDate on Account and ContentVersion sobjects, it works fine, but not for Knowledge__kav.

I tried importing the data both via the API and via APEX. Via the API, the insert is successful, but the CreatedDate is overwritten with the current DateTime. A before insert trigger revealed that CreatedDate was null before insert. Via Apex, I get the error "**FATAL_ERROR System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: Knowledge__kav.CreatedDate**"

I can't find any documentation stating that the behaviour of "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" is different for Knowledge__kav. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The knowledge article [Considerations and activation of 'Create Audit Fields'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331038&type=1&mode=1) has a list of objects that are available for these kinds of updates, and unfortunately Knowledge Article isn't one of them.

Perhaps you could make use of a custom field somehow so that the data is still there?

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you. At least its now clear that this is not supported, even though it's a pitty.

Comment: I talked to salesforce, and they confirmed that it is not possible to allow this for knowledge__kav, and there is already an Idea for this: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000E2SfAAK

Comment: @Andreas86 Voted for the idea!